# Worker Thread, other file than self, cannot find module

Tags: node.js, typescript, multithreading, worker-thread, node-worker-threads

I want to have my worker thread as an external file from the runtime file.

My current folder structure is

```
src/
> service.ts // my 'main'
> thread/
>> test.js
```

inside my `service.ts` i have the following boilerplate code

```
import { Worker, isMainThread } from "worker_threads"

if (isMainThread) {
    const testworker = new Worker('./thread/test.js')
    testworker.on('error', err => console.error({ err }))
    testworker.on('message', msg => console.log({ msg }))
    testworker.on('exit', code => code === 0 ? console.log({ code }) : console.error({ code }))
}
```

inside my `thread/test.js` i have the following boilerplate code

```
import { isMainThread, parentPort } from "worker_threads"

console.log({ isMainThread, parentPort })

parentPort.postMessage("RealCookie")
```

When I attempt to do this, i receive the following error:

```bash
Error: Cannot find module '/srv/FOLDERNAME/thread/test.js'
      at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
      at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
      at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
      at MessagePort.<anonymous> (node:internal/main/worker_thread:191:24)
      at MessagePort.[nodejs.internal.kHybridDispatch] (node:internal/event_target:643:20)
      at MessagePort.exports.emitMessage (node:internal/per_context/messageport:23:28) {
    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    requireStack: []
  }
```

IF i however try to run `const testworker = new Worker(__filename)` then it happily run the code without issues. I do not really understand why?

--node: `v17.9.1`

--npm: `8.11.0`

--tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node16/tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "lib": [
      "es2021"
    ],
    "module": "Node16",
    "target": "es2021",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

--packages

```json
{
  "name": "hidden",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "dist/service.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/node": "^20.4.2",
    "@types/node-cron": "^3.0.8",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.1.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.0",
    "@tsconfig/node16": "^16.1.0",
    "axios": "^1.4.0",
    "core-util-is": "^1.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.2",
    "prisma": "^5.0.0",
    "ulid": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "node dist/service.js",
    "dev": "tsnd --clear src/service",
    "build": "tsc"
  }
}
```

> I really hope this is something simply that I am missing, but at the same time I don't, because I do not want to waste anyones time. Hope someone can see what I am doing wrong here!

Answer (score 2):

Your `tsconfig.json` specifies the build output folder as different from the source:

```json
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "dist",
  }
```

Therefore once you build your project with `tsc`, your TS files are transpiled into JS files, which are placed into that `dist` folder. Which you properly take into account in your start script:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "prod": "node dist/service.js",
  }
```

...but your `thread/test.js` file is not copied into that `dist` folder!

Even though you mention its path for the `new Worker`, `tsc` does not look it up, and does not handle it at all.

Hence `dist/service.js` is unable to spawn a Worker using the relative `./thread/test.js` path.

Simply make sure that after build, that path is still correct / non built file are copied over, to reproduce your source file structure. For example you could do something in the lines of:

```json
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc && cp src/thread/* dist/thread/"
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I will definitely look into this!

Comment: This answer helped me indirectly.  I wanted to call the Worker constructor within one of my controllers (e.g., controllers/FooController.js), and provide it the path of a controllers/worker.js file in the same directory.  But, calling `new Worker( './worker.js' )` did not work.  The path must be relative to the root directory of the web app, i.e., `new Worker( './controllers/worker.js' )`.

Comment: Make sense it spawns from the root folder, but good info!